# intrin.h mingw error : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mingw

I know that `#include<intrin.h>"` is windows specific (and runs in MSVS) but generates an error when I try to compile using MINGW: `fatal error: intrin.h: No such file or directory`
How do I address this issue and get it to compile in MINGW?

FYI, this is what I have in my .cpp where it is complaining and pointing to:

```
...
#elif defined(WIN32)
    #include <intrin.h>
...
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the compiler intrinsics, but I would not expect Visual C++ intrinsics to be available with g++. Or vice versa.

Comment: It is not an SDK file, the compiler supplies it.  [So does GCC](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/introduction-gcc-compiler-intrinsics-vector-processing?page=0,1).

Comment: `intrin.h` is Microsoft Visual C++ specific. It's not one of the Intel defined vector intrinsic headers that GCC provides. Or for that matter one of the header files listed in the article you linked.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, it deserves some form of answer since it is a relatively important topic of modern C/C++ compilers and covers a portability concern between compilers in terms of writing low-level to mid-level code.

Intrinsics by nature are generally non-portable. What intrinsic functions a compiler will provide and how it will provide them will differ from another compiler.

In your case, MSVC's `<intrin.h>` is defined in the include directory for MSVC -- this will be in your Program Files folder for Visual Studio. Header files in this directory are not recognized by default for MinGW. Depending on what intrinsics you're trying to access and what compiler you're using, you'll have to include different headers or access different functions.

---

For example, to access the x86 `CPUID` instruction that's declared in `<intrin.h>` for MSVC, you would have to use `<cpuid.h>` instead with MinGW. This means you'll need conditional compilation for the different compilers your code supports like you do for the different operating systems your code supports:

```cpp
#if defined(_WIN32)
  #if defined(__GNUC__)
    #include <cpuid.h>
  #elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #include <intrin.h>
  #else
    ...
  #endif
#else
  ...
#endif
```

---

Further reading I recommend:

- [Wikipedia's article is a good introduction to intrinsic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function)
- [A more detailed and MSVC-specific description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/compiler-intrinsics?view=msvc-160)
- [Some MinGW64-specific code providing support for MSVC's intrin.h in GCC](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-headers/crt/intrin.h)